# How to get Screen Time (or amount of time spent) on another apps using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, performance

I am trying to fetch the screen time of other apps in my flutter app. For that I have used the following packages:
device_apps: ^2.2.0
app_usage: ^2.1.1
usage_stats: ^1.2.0

But I couldn't find the screen time in fetched data in my snapshot, so I wanna know how to fetch the screen time (usage time [for example used instagram for 15 mins today]):

```
class ScreenTime extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const ScreenTime({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScreenTimeState createState() => _ScreenTimeState();
}

class _ScreenTimeState extends State<ScreenTime> {
  // Future<List<Application>> apps = DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(includeSystemApps: false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          // leading: new IconButton(
          //   icon: new Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
          //   onPressed: () {},
          // ),
        ),
        // ),

        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ListView(children: [
              Table(
                  defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(120.0),
                  border: TableBorder.all(
                      color: Colors.white, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 2),
                  children: [
                    TableRow(children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 65,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 17),
                        color: Color(0xff0307f2),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text('App Icon',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 65,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 17),
                        color: Color(0xff0307f2),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Text('App Name',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white))
                        ]),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 65,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 17),
                        color: Color(0xff0307f2),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            'Screen Time',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
                          )
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ])
                  ]),
              FutureBuilder<List>(
                  future: getApps(),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    } else {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          controller: ScrollController(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            print('${snapshot.data[index]}' + "\n");
                            Uint8List x = snapshot.data[index].icon;
                            double st =
                                ((snapshot.data[index].updateTimeMillis) /
                                    1000);
                            return Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                          height: 105,
                                          width: 125,
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 17),
                                          color: Color(0xff0307f2),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Image.memory(
                                                x,
                                                height: 50,
                                                width: 50,
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          )),
                                      Flexible(
                                        child: Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                            color: Color(0xff9799fc),
                                            height: 105,
                                            width: 130,
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                            child: Text(
                                                '${snapshot.data[index].appName}',
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                                    color: Colors.black))),
                                      ),
                                      Flexible(
                                        child: Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                            color: Color(0xff9799fc),
                                            height: 105,
                                            width: 130,
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                            child: Text(st.toString(),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                                    color: Colors.black))),
                                      )

                                      //   Container(height: 65,padding:EdgeInsets.only(
                                      //       top:17),color:Color(0xff0307f2), child:Column(children:[Text('Screen Time', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white))]),),
                                      // ])

                                      // return Row(
                                      //
                                      //     children:[
                                      //        Image.memory(
                                      //            x,
                                      //          height: 50,
                                      //          width: 50,
                                      //
                                      //        ),
                                      //       Text('${snapshot.data[index]}'),]);
                                      // }
                                    ]));
                          });
                    }
                  }),
            ])));
  }

  Future<List> getApps() async {
    Future<List> x = DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(
        includeSystemApps: true, includeAppIcons: true);
    return x;
  }
}
```

how can I fetch the data regarding usage time of each app here? Or do I need to use some other packages?

Edit 1: I am not having any errors, I just dont know how can I access the screen time of each app in flutter *currently I am fetching update time.
Edit 2: This app is for Android

Comment: What types of exception or error you got?

Comment: You have tagged both Android and iOS but you have mentioned "Screen. time" which is an iOS feature.  Apps do not have access to Screen Time data on iOS.  What platform are you having problems with?

Comment: I have done the necessary edits.